# Maven dependency management between projects

Tags: git, maven, maven-3, dependency-management, repo

Consider this example:

```
parent
+---child1
+---child2
...
\---childn
```

In `parent` I have declared the children as modules, a dependency management for external libs and various common properties. Let's say child1 is at version 1.0.1. Plus, child2-n has in it's dependencies child1. All children are in separate repos..i build the whole project with `repo` for example

My question is..what is the best approach to maintain `child1`'s version in each other children when building the project? should I use a property variable in the parent's pom? Can I keep the property in `child1` project?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: If those children release to reach other which sounds like that you should use a multi module build which having all childs and parent having the same version then you can smply use release plugin or versions-maven-plugin to update version before release etc. Different version in childs does not really make sense...if so don't use modules...

Answer (score 0):

you can try `versions-maven-plugin`.  Using this plugin, you can maintain child1's version.

Comment: Please provide more details in the answer.   Consider re-formatting